# Strange behaviour regarding variable scope and functions (PHP)

Tags: php

While trying to develop on my server I noticed some strange behaviour with a PHP script I am developing. It appears that I can't access a variable declared outside of a function.

I decided to write a simple test.php file to make sure it wasn't caused by my other code, and as a sanity check.

```
<?php
$name = 'Jamie';
function sayMyName(){
    echo "My name is: " . $name;
}
sayMyName();
?>
```

The above code outputs: `My name is:` and my IDE even gives me a warning that `$name` is unassigned.

I haven't used PHP in some time, but I'm pretty sure this is valid?

Could this be something to do with PHP's settings, and if so, any idea what's causing this? - I'm on a HostGator shared hosting package so I can't imagine the default settings would be too obscure.

Comment: Pass it to your function `sayMyName($name)` in both instances.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the variable to a global variable so the function can access it.

```
<?php
$name = 'Jamie';
global $name;
function sayMyName(){
    echo "My name is: " . $name;
}
sayMyName();
?>
```

Alternatively you can pass the variable to the function.

```
<?php
$name = 'Jamie';
function sayMyName($name){
    echo "My name is: " . $name;
}
sayMyName($name);
?>
```

Comment: or pass the variable as a parameter

Comment: I recommend the second option.

Comment: It would appear I've been playing with JS and Python too much lately, so to clarify by default PHP has never automatically included variables from the same file into the scope of a function?

Answer (score 0):

```
function sayMyName($name){
    echo "My name is: " . $name;
}
sayMyName('Jamie');
```

in a class

```
class sayMyName
{
public function setName($name) {
return "My name is: ".$name;
}
}
$myname=New sayMyName();
echo $myname->setName('Jamie');
```

Comment: It would appear I've been playing with JS and Python too much lately, so to clarify, by default PHP has never automatically included variables from the same file into the scope of a function?

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1923a74288353bf348c38167efe0e9c07426b129

Comment: That's both correct and incorrect. It's correct given the examples present on this page but incorrect if we're talking about classes. As class properties are accessible by the class methods(functions) using `$this->propertyName`

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e76a97e108e23932b6a36dac64c295335d4cb93c